# Extracting split .tar files on linux, that separately need to be decrypted

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tar, extract

i am trying to extract and decrypt 23 .tar files named as per below:

```
dev_flash_000.tar.aa.2010_07_29_170013
```

There are 23 of them, and each needs to be decrypted with an app called dePKG before it is extracted.

I tried this bash script:

```
for i in `ls dev_flash*`; do ./depkg $i $i.tar ; tar -xvf ./$i.tar ; rm $i.tar; done
```

and get this error for all 23 files:

> read 0x800 bytes of pkg
>   pkg data @ 340 with size 3ec
>   not inflated, writing 1004 bytes
>   tar: This does not look like a tar archive
>   tar: Skipping to next header
>   tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

I just want to save time :D

Comment: are you able to decrypt and extract by hand?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use ls in a ` ` context — see http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#ls . FWIW:

```
for i in dev_flash*`; do
    ./depkg "$i" -;
done | tar -xv;
```

Check with your depkg manual pages on how to make it output to stdout, or if it does not, use `/dev/stdout` as a file. Not only does that save you the temporaries, but running a single tar command on the concatenation of the decrypted contents also works properly when the original archive has been split at arbitrary positions.